# How to make same URL scheme but different route and component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have some dynamic and static URLS, I am ibiut but confused how to call different component on same route structure, pleas have a look below

**Required Routes structure: **

```
https://example.com/:pagename (dynamic)
https://example.com/:countryname (dynamic)

https://example.com/about-us (static)
```

**Current Route:**

```
<Route path='/:pageName' component={Page} exact />
<Route path='/:countryname' component={Country} exact />
<Route path='/about-us' component={AboutUs} exact />
```

Thanks

Comment: Sadly, that is not possible, but there is one work around that I can think of, you need to write some logic in your component and just define the single route. Let me know you want to try that I can post a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is to change your URL logic as follows:

`https://example.com/page/:pagename` or `https://example.com/p/:pagename`

`https://example.com/country/:countryname` or `https://example.com/c/:countryname`

and the Routes:

```
<Route path='/page/:pageName' component={Page} exact />
<Route path='/country/:countryname' component={Country} exact />
```

The Route algorithm stops at the first URL-pattern that matches the query. Consider the following two URLs:

- https://example.com/homepage
- https://example.com/germany

Both of these URLs match the first pattern (`https://example.com/:pagename`) as the matching algorithm won't know that "germany" is not a pagename.

If you can't go this way you could build a sub-routing component which checks whether the first parameters after example.com matches any country name or any page name and based on that render the corresponding component:

```
    <Route path='/:pageNameOrCountryNameNotSure' component={SubRouter} exact />
```

However, this is not a clean solution and is **not recommended**.